# How to count cells containing certain digits in a column of a data frame

Tags: r, indexing

I need to find the number of elements of a vector containing two precise digits, let's say 00.

I thought about using logical indexing but the way R reacts makes me think it is looking for the exact value 00, while I want to know how many times 00 can be found INSIDE the numbers contained in the vector.

Is there a function that does that or some kind of logical indexing I could use?

Comment: Hi Tommaso! Could you provide a reproducible example? I'm not sure I got what you meant. Maybe `grepl("00",v)` is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Nicola, thanks for the help provided! Yes that was the function I needed to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, one work around is to use `str_count` from `stringr` as follows:

```
 df<-data.frame(A=c("00","89","00"))

Sums<-str_count(df$A,"00")
sum(Sums>0)
```

Using base R and adapting a little of nicola's answer:

```
sum(grepl("00",df$A)==T)
```

Comment: Yes both codes worked! I didn't want to use stringr package because of knitting problems so I went for the second in the end. Thanks!